# Automatic Type Promotion in Java

Tags: java, casting, int, byte

I understand that the operands are automatically converted to int and we need to cast the expression to byte again. And for byte conversion the 24 bits are truncated and only 8 bits are evaluated. But I am not able to understand this output -56. The final value of e is 200 and converting it in binary gives 11001000. How is the output -56?

```
 public class ByteIntAutomaticPromotionInExpressions {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            byte e = 50;
            e = (byte)(e *2);
            System.out.println(e);
            e *= 2;
            System.out.println(e);


    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
100
-56
```

Comment: It's an overflow: `100 * 2` falls out of the byte range. `(byte) 200` returns `byte` `-56`

Comment: This happens because of overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here:

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

If the data type was unsigned, 11001000 would be 200 in decimal.
But since it is signed, you treat it like a negative binary number which is -(inverted bits +1) => - (0110111 + 1) = -(0111000) = -56

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-2/negative-binary-numbers/

Comment: When an int is typecast to a byte the first 8 bits are considered and rest are truncated but 200 itself is 8 bit..thus you went to find negative of it? Because when it is 257 we do not find it's 2's complement, we have last 8 digits as 1.And I agree when you convert 200 to it's negative, we use 2's complement, but why did you write the minus sign beforehand? Isn't it that the first bit is sign bit and 1 means negative and 0 means positive. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for the delay.
8-bit signed means 7 bits for the number and the first bit for the sign.
Unsigned 200 is 11001000 in binary. 
When using that binary number as signed byte, it becomes: 1 for sign and 1001000 for the number. To make sense out of this you do twos complement:
 you invert the 7 bits (1001000) to 0110111 and add 1. 
I wrote the minus sign before hand to represent the conversion of the first binary bit to the decimal '-' symbol.

11001000 : unsigned => 200. 
11001000 : signed =>

TwosComplement(10111000) =>

-(0110111 + 1)

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

8 bits, 2^8=256 in this case 200-256 = -56